# Browser preview in localhost

Tags: sublimetext2

I realize they're ways to open files in a browser (builds, plugins, and packages).
What I want to do is have the file open locally.I maybe missing something because it used to work. RIght now the preview generates the following in the navigation file:///Applications/MAMP/htdocs/xxxx.dev/index.html instead of localhost

I know since I am using LiveReload, I could just type in I know since I am using LiveReload, I could just type in localhost once and it would refresh afterwards on it's own. And for that matter I could do that in all my testing browsers. But that would mean at least 3 other times!

Come on there has to be folks like me who have watched Paul Irish and want to be efficient!

I have been searching for a few days and don't feel like going back to coda2...Please help!once and it would refresh afterwards on it's own. And for that matter I could do that in all my testing browsers. But that would mean at least 3 other times!

Come on there has to be folks like me who have watched Paul Irish and want to be efficient!

I have been searching for a few days and don't feel like going back to coda2...Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps this plugin will help you?

https://github.com/wattsin/Sublime-Text---Open-And-View